# Report crash on live deploy, works just fine locally in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

I just migrated a VS2008 app to VS2013. Everything works great locally. However, when deployed, the report I have crashes with the following error:

```
    An error occurred during local report processing.
The report definition for report 'myReport' has not been specified
Could not find file 'D:\docroot\appdev\wsds\application\Report\myReport.rdlc'.
```

Called from my aspx page as so:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="myReport" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" Height="750px" Width="850px" >
    <localreport reportpath="Report\myReport.rdlc">
        <datasources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="dsReportStuff" 
                Name="reportStuffDataSet_reportStuff" />
        </datasources>
    </localreport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

What the even heck is going on? This code worked great on my old '08 install which used report viewer 10. I have upgraded to report viewer 11 due to the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrasingly, I figured it out... Still kinda new to .NET, and it shows. Apparently when you publish a new project, .NET doesn't copy over .rdlc files.

So I had a report folder sitting on my server with all of my .aspx files, but no report files. Didn't even think to check on that (*slaps head*).

Boo.

EDIT:

Then a few weeks later (after migrating a number of VS08 apps to VS13), I figured out that there is a very simple setting to make sure the .rdlc files are copied over. Just select the .rdlc file, and in the properties window, ensure 'Build Action' is set to 'Content' (mine were all set to 'Embedded Resource'). I also set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy Always'.

Just thought I'd add this in case this is happening to anyone else that finds themselves here.